# Force install php 7 packages on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: apt, php, composer

While I know that php 8 is the default PHP choice on Ubuntu 22.04, I still use php 7 for my project. When installing packages related to PHP, the dependancies always pick `php-common, php-*`, etc.. and end up installing php 8 on the server.

Currently I have trouble installing Composer via `apt install composer`

So how do I tell the system that php-* is always mapped to php7.4-* and force libraries to always pick this given php version?

Comment: "I have trouble installing Composer" - what exactly does that mean?

Comment: It ended up installing php8 and after that when you run "composer --version", errors display instead of running properly.

Comment: Why not share that error message such that others could provide a hint about how to resolve that error?

Answer (score 2):

PHP7 is no longer available in the core repository of Ubuntu 22.04, but you can install it using the PPA documented at [https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/)

Comment: I've already installed ondrej PPA. I know it's old but I still want the php core to always pick the prefered version of php. Not possible?

Comment: That might be possible, but as you haven't told how you install any other package, it's difficult to guess where this goes wrong

Answer (score 1):

To add support for older php version to be installed:

> add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php && apt update -y

AFter you install the php7.4 packages you need, the following command will prompt you to select the default php version:

> sudo update-alternatives --config php

Comment: You need `sudo` for `apt update` as well and it won't be inherited by the second part of your command.